# Real time multiplayer Quizz app

Tags: php, android

What are the steps should I follow to create Real-time Multiplayer Quiz App? I created an Application in which users get registered with my app and information of users are saved inside the app server. But I am not able to create the connection between two or more users to create an Online real-time Quiz environment.

Comment: thnk u for the response. Actually i implemented firebase in my app for Notifications. But in my app i am using my own server database, so should i use firebase database to implement connection between clients..

Comment: ok i got it, i can save user details inside app server, n for store connection state only i should go with Firebase DB. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should learn [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com). From that you can now easily use **Realtime** database, that will be super helpful in your application. And you can store user details too in Firebase Database.
As I've done here: 
[image]